# how to give parameters in url for getting json parse for both taxonomy terms AND nodes

Tags: 7, services

i created 2 nodes in Company CCK under taxonomy A, 2 nodes in Company CCk under taxonomy B. now i want to get a json parse for all the nodes in a taxonomy A.

I tried like this www.mywebsite/api/taxonomy_term?selectNodes&parameters[tid]=1 it gives the value of that taxonomy term but, i wont get nodes under that category . In what way the url  should be framed for attaining values of nodes of a particular category(taxonomy) i.e i would like to filter the nodes of my choice.

so any one help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: Ya ,In drupal7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `taxonomy_select_nodes` to find all nodes associated with a term.

Return nodes attached to a term across all field instances.

**Parameters**

**$tid:** The term ID.

**$pager:** Boolean to indicate whether a pager should be used.

**$limit:** Integer. The maximum number of nodes to find. Set to FALSE for no limit.

**$order:** An array of fields and directions.

[API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7)

Comment: Is it not possible through url instead of code?

Comment: How is that possible ? !!!!

Comment: suppose if i want to get node values of content type named machine url will be www.website.com/api/node?parameters[type]=machine this gives me all the nodes of machine content type. i am using REST server